# Delphi 2010 and .net

Tags: .net, delphi, delphi-2010

how is Delphi 2010 relationship with .net? I remember that not long ago you could only generate .net 1.1 code. And now, how is that?

How does legacy Delphi code (mostly 7) behave when compiled for the .net platform instead of Win32? Is it compatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could argue that Embarcadero's support for .Net is better than it ever was.  Delphi Prism is completely up to date with the latest version of the framework, and even includes [features not available in C#](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Delphi_Prism_vs._CSharp).

I was a huge fan of VCL.Net, so I'm kind of torn on the subject.  I liked the ability to share library code between platforms and the visual portion of VCL.Net was better suited to client applications than Winforms.

However, with Borland (at that time) writing functionality that duplicated what was already in Visual Studio (e.g. designers) took resources away from native Delphi and left them constantly playing catch up and unable to support the latest version of the framework.

Even I had to admit that the current support outweighs the loss of VCL.Net.  I have to say, it's refreshing to use Pascal in ASP.Net projects.

Answer (score 3):

The "Delphi for .NET" project is dead as of the last two releases.  It's been replaced by Prism from RemObjects, which is more or less compatible, but there's no VCL and some of the syntax is different.

Comment: That's just sad. I remember when Borland tried to embrace most of the platforms with Kylix, Delphi 8, etc. 

It's true, they all failed.

Comment: And Prism runs in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism)